# GLSL (ES 3.0): reference a uniform using another uniform's location and an offset

Tags: opengl-es, glsl, glsles

In GLSL for OpenGL ES 3.0, if I have the following code:

```
uniform mat4 matrix1;
uniform mat4 matrix2;
uniform mat4 matrix3;
```

is it possible to reference matrix2 or matrix3, using only the location of matrix1 plus an offset? This has to be dynamic i.e. the index will be an attribute.

EDIT: I mean using matrix2 and matrix3 in the shader itself with only the location of matrix1 and an offset, not getting the location of them on the CPU.

EDIT 2: In case it helps I'll add more context. I'm trying to solve [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20388086/opengl-es-3-0-matrix-array-only-using-first-matrix) GPU-skinning issue, and it's come to my attention that Adreno doesn't support indexing uniform arrays with anything other than constant integers in their vertex shaders (contrary to what the OpenGL ES 3.0 GLSL spec mandates). I'm thinking of storing the array of matrices individually one after the other now, however still need to be able to access them with an index provided as an attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I mean using matrix2 and matrix3 in the shader itself with only the location of matrix1 and an offset, not getting the location of them on the CPU.

No, this cannot be done.

Uniform locations are only assigned after ***linking*** shaders, and there is no requirement that they be assigned sequentially in the same order that they appear in the shader source. While this is the only behavior I have ever witnessed, it is not a requirement.

---

> Adreno doesn't support indexing uniform arrays with anything other than constant integers in their vertex shaders (contrary to what the OpenGL ES 3.0 GLSL spec mandates).

As for indexing uniforms by anything other than constant integers, this behavior depends on the shader stage, which you are already aware. In vertex shaders you can index them using any integer expression you want, in fragment shaders implementations are only required to support ***constant-index*** (though many support more than this). A constant integer and constant-index expression are not the same thing, constant-index is a little bit less restrictive (and can include loop control variables in some cases).

That said, dynamically indexing elements within a matrix is not guaranteed to be supported... (*e.g.* `vec4 column = matrix1 [some_variable];`). Some implementations will support this, others will not.

Are you correctly prefixing your GLSL shader with `#version 300 es`? The behavior described above applies to GLSL ES 1.0, which is what you will default to if you do not tell the compiler otherwise. A compliant implementation will give you a different set of restrictions if you do not use `#version 300 es`.

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer, I didn't think there was any way to do pointer-type behaviour but worth asking! Yep I'm prefixing the shader with the correct version (300 es). You wrote that "dynamically indexing elements within a matrix is not guaranteed to be supported", I maybe have misread the specification but I thought that the array indexing stuff would apply to all types (including matrices)? Either way you're right, on Adreno using a uniform array of vec4s works well enough and is what they do in their SDK so I did the same :)

Comment: @Rajveer: No, that is definitely not the case. Matrices are not really arrays, you have the ability to index them like arrays to access individual columns in the matrix but they are not arrays. The same way if you have `vec3 foo`, you can write `foo [0]` to mean `foo.x` (even though a `vec3` is not the same thing as `float [3]`), but if you had something like `int i = 0` and tried to use `foo [i]` to mean `foo.x` implementations are not required to support that.

Comment: Ah I'm sorry, I misread what you wrote. I thought you were talking about an array of matrices, not treating a single matrix as an array of vecs. In which case dynamically indexing a uniform array of matrices should work just like dynamically indexing a uniform array of vec4s (within the vertex shader of course).

Comment: @Rajveer: Yeah, it should. If you have a uniform array of `mat4`'s rather than using several differently named `mat4` uniforms it actually satisfies one of the  properties you wanted. Each `mat4` is allocated 4 sequential uniform locations (1 per-column) and each `mat4` in the array is also distributed sequentially. So if you do it this way, then you will be guaranteed the ability to reference a particular `mat4` by a base uniform location + an offset. To get the n'th `mat4` in your uniform array it would be `base_loc + (4 * (n-1))`. Though you said your implementation does not like that :-\

Answer (score 0):

Uniform variables MUST be read from OpenGL using glGetUniformLocation.

They are not "generated" until compile time (and can change due to shader optimisation)

Comment: I'm talking about using matrix2/matrix3 with only the location of matrix1 and an offset in the shader itself, not getting the location of matrix2/matrix3 on the CPU using glGetUniformLocation with matrix1 and an offset. Sorry for any confusion.